# sports tournament draw formula

Tags: combinations

Suppose we have a sport tournament with direct elimination. The original number of players is a perfect power of 2, say n. 
Each player is attributed a draw position, between 1 and n. 
The tournament's first round is organized in the following way:

- match 1: 1 vs 2
- match 2: 3 vs 4
- ...
- match n/2: n-1 vs n

Matches are numbered in order from top to bottom for each round.

Given a particular match, how can we express the range each player draw position can be from the round number and the match number ?

e.g:

- Round 2, match 1:
- P1 is in [1,2]
- P2 is in [3,4]

Round x, match m: 
P1 is in ? 
P2 is in ?

Thank you

Comment: if you -1 me please say why thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round X, match m:

P1 is in $[(m-1)2^X+1 , (m-1)2^X +2^{X-1}] $

P2 is in $[(m-1)2^X +2^{X-1}+1 , m 2^X] $

Comment: works wonderfully thanks a lot.